# Javascript query with switch

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and trying to complete what should be a simple task of getting the user to interact with a simple contacts array, I am struggling to find the correct syntax to loop through the choice variable until the user enters 0 to quit, i have tried a while loop and for but just not sure exactly where i should be putting the loop and advice would be grateful

```
var Contact = {
    //Initialise the contact
    init: function(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    },
    //Display the contact details
    describe: function() {
        var description = "Last name : " + this.lastName + ", first name: " + this.firstName; 
        return description
    }
};

var contact1 = Object.create(Contact);
contact1.init("John", "Smith");

var contact2 = Object.create(Contact);
contact2.init("Jane", "Doe");

var contacts = [];
contacts.push(contact1);
contacts.push(contact2);


console.log("Welcome to your contacts manager!");
console.log("1: List contacts");
console.log("2: Add a contact");
console.log("0: Quit");


var choice = "";
choice = prompt("Enter 1, 2 or 0");

//while (choice !== "0") {

switch (choice) {
case "1": 
    console.log("Here's the list of all your contacts:");
    contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
    console.log(contact.describe());
    });
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;

case "2": 
    contacts.push(prompt("Enter new name: "));
    console.log("Contact added");
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;

case "0":
    console.log("Goodbye");
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;

default:
    console.log("Invalid Entry");
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the updated while loop

```js
var Contact = {
    //Initialise the contact
    init: function(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    },
    //Display the contact details
    describe: function() {
        var description = "Last name : " + this.lastName + ", first name: " + this.firstName; 
        return description
    }
};

var contact1 = Object.create(Contact);
contact1.init("John", "Smith");

var contact2 = Object.create(Contact);
contact2.init("Jane", "Doe");

var contacts = [];
contacts.push(contact1);
contacts.push(contact2);


console.log("Welcome to your contacts manager!");
console.log("1: List contacts");
console.log("2: Add a contact");
console.log("0: Quit");

var choice = "";
while(choice != "0"){

choice = prompt("Enter 1, 2 or 0");

switch (choice) {
case "1": 
    console.log("Here's the list of all your contacts:");
    contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
    console.log(contact.describe());
    });
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;

case "2": 
    contacts.push(prompt("Enter new name: "));
    console.log("Contact added");
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;

case "0":
    console.log("Goodbye");
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;

default:
    console.log("Invalid Entry");
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;
    }
}
```

**Update**

```js
var Contact = {
    //Initialise the contact
    init: function(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    },
    //Display the contact details
    describe: function() {
        var description = "Last name : " + this.lastName + ", first name: " + this.firstName; 
        return description
    }
};

var contact1 = Object.create(Contact);
contact1.init("John", "Smith");

var contact2 = Object.create(Contact);
contact2.init("Jane", "Doe");

var contacts = [];
contacts.push(contact1);
contacts.push(contact2);


console.log("Welcome to your contacts manager!");
console.log("1: List contacts");
console.log("2: Add a contact");
console.log("0: Quit");

var choice = "";
while(choice != "0"){

choice = prompt("Enter 1, 2 or 0");

switch (choice) {
case "1": 
    console.log("Here's the list of all your contacts:");
    contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
    console.log(contact.describe());
    });
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;

case "2": 
 firstname = prompt("Enter first name: ");
 lastname = prompt("Enter last name: ")
    var contactnew = Object.create(Contact);
 contactnew.init(firstname, lastname);
 contacts.push(contactnew);
    console.log("Contact added");
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;

case "0":
    console.log("Goodbye");
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;

default:
    console.log("Invalid Entry");
    console.log("1: List contacts");
    console.log("2: Add a contact");
    console.log("0: Quit");
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i ask you a question about this while loop, it all works fine going through the first time but if i add a contact using the push and then try and list the array it fails as it says the contact.describe is no longer a function?

Comment: Yes so it was in your code, you try to initialize 2 values and in input you taking the name as single value, No issues I have updated your code please try now Please see the updated part.

Answer (score 0):

You want the user to enter multiple things, so you may put prompt into the loop:

```
var choice = "";
while (choice !== "0") {
  choice = prompt("Enter 1, 2 or 0");
  switch(choice){
   //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In switch case you are checking for String "0". Use case 0: or convert input to string and pass the data to switch.

Comment: The input is in string format... `:)` ps: Not my downvote.